# List of dataframes, how to turn character variables into numeric without unlisting?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large dataset I had to partition into 20 smaller subsets to aid in processing speed. I am running all tidying and processing in parallel using for loops. Each row is a sample.

I need to calculate a numerical variable based on the numerical value of a few columns. The problem is that since they are in a list of data frames, I can't (don't know how to) turn the columns of interest into numerical instead of strings of characters.

```
df1 <- c(0, NA, 5)
df2 <- c(2, 3, NA)

list <- list(df1, df2)

VAF_MX <- c()
for (i in 1:20){
VAF_MX[[i]] <- matrix(nrow = length(tidy_gvcf[[i]]$Genotype))
for (n in (1:nrow(recoding_trial[[i]])){
VAF_MX[[i]][n] <-(recoding_trial[[i]][n]$alt_1/((recoding_trial[[i]][n,1])+recoding_trial[[i]][n,2]))
}
}
```

Note: NAs are expected and ok, I keep them so matching to sample ID later on is feasible.

I attempted converting the variables into numeric as follows

```
for (n in 1:20){

recoding_trial[[n]][,c(1,2)] <- as.numeric(recoding_trial[[n]][,c(1,2)]
}
```

> Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Just FYI, on Stack Overflow (and in markdown generally), use a single backtick for code that is "in-line", that is code that is mixed with non-code text in the same line. For code on its own lines, you don't need the single backticks, you use indentation instead, not in addition.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the formatting, Gregor!

Comment: It would help a lot if you improved your example. You create two vectors named `df1` and `df2` and put them in a list. This is a list of vectors, but you say you have a list of data frames. In the next couple lines, you use objects we don't have and can't see, where is `tidy_gvcf`? Is that supposed to be the same as `list`? If so, it needs data frames that have a `Genotype` column. And then your next line uses `recoding_trial`, which we also don't know what it is. It's hard to help when we can't understand the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any sample data here, but let's create a list with two data frames called `recoding_trial`. The first two columns of each data frame are numbers stored as character vectors, as in your example.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(y = as.character(11:20), z = as.character(21:30), x = 1:10)
df2 <- df1[10:1,]
recoding_trial <- list(df1, df2)
```

We can see the first column of the first data frame is a character vector:

```
recoding_trial[[1]][,1]
#>  [1] "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20"
```

To make these character columns numeric, we can use `lapply` like this:

```
recoding_trial <- lapply(recoding_trial, function(d) {
  d[1:2] <- lapply(d[1:2], as.numeric); d
  })
```

Now we have

```
recoding_trial
#> [[1]]
#>     y  z  x
#> 1  11 21  1
#> 2  12 22  2
#> 3  13 23  3
#> 4  14 24  4
#> 5  15 25  5
#> 6  16 26  6
#> 7  17 27  7
#> 8  18 28  8
#> 9  19 29  9
#> 10 20 30 10
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     y  z  x
#> 10 20 30 10
#> 9  19 29  9
#> 8  18 28  8
#> 7  17 27  7
#> 6  16 26  6
#> 5  15 25  5
#> 4  14 24  4
#> 3  13 23  3
#> 2  12 22  2
#> 1  11 21  1
```

And we can confirm our columns are numeric now:

```r
recoding_trial[[1]][,1]
#>  [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, Thank you both for the suggestion of how to best write questions. Will be sure to implement it for future questions. in the function when you type d[1:2] is this referencing the two dataframes in the list or the two columns for each dataframe in the list? 

thank you for your help

Comment: `d[1:2]` is referencing the first two columns of each data frame. It is equivalent to `d[,c(1,2)]`